# failing to find ENV['SECRET_KEY'] in devise setup on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

This gist on [not version-controlling your secret keys](https://gist.github.com/cjolly/6265302) is awesome, and I've used it a few times now for no-longer versioning my rails secret-key-base.

I tried using it for the devise secret_key on heroku and my attempt failed miserably. It works fine in dev, but refused to allow me to push to heroku - saying the devise key which I created (in the same way as in the gist above) wasn't set.

I got it working with a hard-coded secret-key (checked into git), but not when I used the following:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.secret_key = ENV['DEVISE_SECRET_KEY']
...
```

(with associated environment variable triple-checked that it was there)

It seems to fail on precompiling assets during the push to heroku

```
$  git push heroku master
     ... (bundle stuff here)
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       Devise.secret_key was not set. Please add the following to your Devise initializer:
       config.secret_key = '0cfa796871e0...
   /tmp/build_.../vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.1.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:446:in `raise_no_secret_key'
   /tmp/build_.../vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.1.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:195:in `devise_for'
   /tmp/build_.../config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
    ...( rest of the long stacktrace with little of interest here)
```

the error is being raised when "devise_for" is run in the routes directory.
relevant line:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout'}
```

The relevant line in the actual devise gem is:

```
      raise_no_secret_key unless Devise.secret_key
```

So it really is just checking if the secret_key got set.

just to confirm... I checked the heroku config, and I did in fact put a secret key into the environment under that name.

```
DEVISE_SECRET_KEY:            3f844454bee...(more here)
RAILS_SECRET_KEY_BASE:        04bf569d4e...(more here)
```

because it's in a rake task instead of the app - I'm guessing that's why it can't get to the ENV???

any ideas on where I might begin looking for a solution?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're wanting to use a [config var](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) before (at compile time) it's actually made available to your app (at slug compilation time).

Try switching on the [Heroku Labs: user-env-compile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile)

I suspect it will solve the problem.

Comment: The page you linked to says the 'user-env-compile' feature is now deprecated.

Comment: Like @odigity says, this isn't working anymore. Anyone know what to do now?

Comment: I've given up and decided to fall in-line with Heroku's guideline and make sure no env vars are accessed during the buildstep, which I assume (based on learned the hard way) that this includes any rake tasks, presumably because they run rake to compile assets or something. I wrapped my custom tasks in "if Rails.env.development?" statements. Would like something more elegant, but... :(

Comment: Heroku runs `rake assets:precompile`. Wish I better understand what parts of Rails gets loaded by that. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby/blob/master/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb

Answer (score 5):

If it's breaking at compile time you need to enable user-env-compile, `heroku labs:enable user-env-compile` to make the environment available when the application boots to compile the assets.

Comment: thanks - it worked.

You both gave me the answer, but the other guy has fewer points, so I'm being nice to him and giving him the accept ;)

Comment: That's ok - Jon a nice chap :)

Comment: That feature has been deprecated. Running the above heroku command yields: "!    No such feature: user-env-compile".

Answer (score 2):

The user-env-compile labs feature is not available anymore on Heroku.

I'm using Ruby 2.2.2p95 and Rails 4.2.4.

What worked for me is, in config/initializers/devise.rb:

```
config.secret_key = ENV['DEVISE_SECRET_KEY'] if Rails.env.production?
```

Then add the DEVISE_SECRET_KEY config var in heroku, set to whatever you want. Good practice is to generate something with the same length as the default value for development and test.

Hope this helps.